# Doubling the trapezoid

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I recently came across a puzzle I had trouble solving:

> In a Trapezoid ABCD, $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ are the parallel sides, the perpendicular of $D$ intersects $\overline{AB}$ at P and $\overline{AC}$ at $Q$.
> Prove that $\overline{CQ}$ is double the length$\overline{AD}$ only when $\angle CAD$ is double the size of $\angle BAC$.

I tried to fill in some angles using basic theorems and this is how far I got.

[image: Trapezoid image]

I noticed that $\triangle APQ$ and $\triangle QCD$ are similar, bt that doesn't seem to help much.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are to prove that if $CQ=2AD$, then $\angle{CAD}=2\angle{BAC}$.

---

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $CQ$. It's clear that $M$ is the circumcenter
of $\triangle{CDQ}$ because $\angle{CDQ}=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Let $\angle{BAC}=\alpha$. Since $DM=CM$, we have $$\angle{MCD}=\angle{MDC}=\alpha\,,$$ and thus $$\angle AMD=\angle{MCD}+\angle{MDC}=2\alpha\,.$$ Since $AD=DM=\frac{CQ}{2}$, we have $$\angle{CAD}=\angle{MAD}=\angle{AMD}=2\alpha\,.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nice solution